# AWS IoT MQTT Client with Apache camel-mqtt

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, mqtt, aws-iot, spring-integration-mqtt

I am looking into building a AWS IoT Java Client with Apache Camel ( using camel-mqtt ) + Spring Boot. It sounds like a good match to me, but couldn't find any examples. Is there any drawback that I can't see ? Would be interested to see any pointers.

Comment: You may also look at using camel-paho as Eclipse Paho is a bit more maintained project than the MQTT client that camel-mqtt uses. For examples you can look at the IoT bloggers. Some have shown how to do this with Camel, MQTT and IoT devices.

Comment: Thanks @ClausIbsen ! , do you know any good example  camel-paho used to connect to AWS IoT ?  I couldn't seem find any solid example.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working with the below configuration. sslContext bean holds the certificate/security :

```
    @Bean
    RouteBuilder awsIoTRoute() {

        return new RouteBuilder() {

            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {

                from("timer://foo?repeatCount=0&delay=5000&fixedRate=true&period=17s")
                    .setBody(simple("TEST MESSAGE"))
                    .to("mqtt:awsIoTPublisher?host=ssl://{{aws.iot.host}}:8883&publishTopicName={{aws.iot.pub.topic}}&clientId={{aws.iot.pub.clientId}}&sslContext=#sslContext")
                    .log("Sent :"+body().convertToString().toString());

                from("mqtt:awsIoTReciever?host=ssl://{{aws.iot.host}}:8883&subscribeTopicName={{aws.iot.sub.topic}}&clientId={{aws.iot.sub.clientId}}&sslContext=#sslContext").log("Recieved : "+body().convertToString());


            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: How can I configure sslContext?